# How to get width and height of user pictures?

Tags: 7, media

It seems that Drupal doesn't store the width and height of uploaded user profile pictures (standard profile, not profile2).

I would like to be able to link the profile thumbnail to a larger version if the uploaded image is larger than 480 pixels.

Is that possible without jumping through too many hoops?

I can require new users to upload pictures with a minimum size but I have imported lots of profile pictures and many are smaller than 480 pixels wide or high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an image field to the user entity. Then you can create a custom field formatter that can check if images are over a certain size and display a link to the larger size if they are. Here is an article on creating a field formater in Drupal 7: http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to so everything with Image cache. Create a layout for the user profile picture and tell fields to link to the original One.

Comment: thanks. I don't want to link to the original if the original isn't larger enough. However, for simplicity I might just do that. I'm sure one day user pictures will be real entities in Drupal which will solve this issue.